# Android studio 1.0.2 cannot resolve symbol R in all java sources except MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have MainActivity under package com.example.example. I have several fragments under com.example.example.fragments. I have several classes under com.example.example.utils.

While MainActivity is ok, all the others have problems resolving symbol R. I moved one of them to com.example.example but still had a problem so I moved it back to com.example.example.utils and suddenly it was OK but then I realized it added com.example.example.R to the import section. Though it did work I removed it because it's a workaround and not a fix (MainActivity doesn't have this import in its section).

All my XML files have a green indication so it's not that (I think). I read a lot of posts about this issue but nothing helped, neither clean nor build. What else can cause this error?

Update: Apparently, when moving all sources under com.example.example it does work so the question should be: how can I make it work when sources are under a different package inside the main com.example.example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this not a work around. If you take a look at your manifest, the root level tag has the `package="com.example.example"` attribute. This is indeed the correct behavior. That is the namespace of the application package, and all resources are located there. The reason your `MainActivity` does not have this is because it is located within the package namespace, in your case its package is already `com.example.example`.

Comment: So in order for the other classes to work under a sub folder (I did it solely for organizational purposes), I have to import com.example.example.R? That is the best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Yes. Do a little searching on what `R` in Android is. Since it follows the normal Java package conventions, its simply a package thing. I had a similar situation not too long ago. I have accepted it :)

Comment: I created the sub folders just so it will be cleaner to view where things are. I thought R is smarter than this :)